# Print out every fifth character

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm practicing my assembly language and what I'm trying to do is to get it to print out every fifth character I type. The problem is that it only prints the first and 6th character. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
include irvine32.inc
Title characters
.data
fort db "Enter here:",0
.code
main proc
mov ecx,10
mov edx, offset fort
mov eax,0
call crlf
call writestring
call crlf
call crlf
call readstring
call crlf
call crlf
L1:
mov al, [edx]
add dx,5
call writechar
call crlf
loop L1
exit
main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that instruction `add dx,5` should be `add edx,5`.  Referring to 'dx' forces 16-bit register width, so the value in dx after the add will roll over beyond 0xFFFFF.  Not what you want.  This roll over bug could happen quickly depending on the initial pointer value in edx.

Answer (score 0):

1) The main issue is called ["Off by one error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). The first character is at index position 0. At index position 5 (0+5) is the sixth character. The next index position is 10 (5+5) where the eleventh character resides. I guess, you wanted to show the indexes 4,9,14..., so increment first `EDX` by 4 and add then repeatedly 5 to it.

2) Irvine's [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) writes maximal 10 (`ECX`) characters to `[EDX]` (`fort`: "Enter here:\0"). There is no reaction, if the input is bigger than `ECX` allows, the written string is just been cropped. After an input of "12345678901234567890" the memory at `fort` looks like "123456789\0:\0". There is only one "fifth" character, the 10th character is the string-terminating null. I suggest to define a separate variable for the input with much more space.

3) The [`LOOP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_161.html) also applies to `ECX`, which was set to 10 at the beginning of the program and accidentally not changed by the functions [`WriteString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fwritestring.htm), [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) and [`Crlf`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fcrlf.htm). Therefore the loop will repeat 10 times incrementing the memory pointer `EDX` by 5. It will read the memory far beyond the space which was filled by [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm). I suggest to create an endless loop ([`JMP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html) instead of [`LOOP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_161.html)) with a separate break condition based on the string length.

Summary:

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
fort db "Enter here:",0
entered db 100 DUP (0)          ; Reserve space for 100 bytes and fill them with 0
terminating dd OFFSET entered   ; Pointer to the terminating null of the string

.code
main proc
    mov edx, offset fort
    call crlf
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    call Crlf

    mov ecx,100                 ; Maximal count of characters for ReadString
    mov edx, offset entered     ; Pointer to string
    call ReadString             ; Returnsin `EAX` the size of the input
    add terminating, eax        ; Pointer to the terminating null of the input
    call Crlf
    call Crlf


    mov edx, offset entered+4   ; Pointer to the fifth character of the string
    L1:
    cmp edx, terminating        ; Does it point beyond the string?
    jae J1                      ; Yes -> break the loop.
    mov al, [edx]
    add edx,5
    call WriteChar
    call Crlf
    jmp L1                      ; Endless loop
    J1:

    exit
main endp
end main
```